# C++ precise garbage collector using clang/llvm?

Tags: c++, garbage-collection, clang

Ok so I'm wanting to write a precise 'mark and sweep' garbage collector in C++.  I have hopefully made some decisions that can help me as in all my pointers will be wrapped in a 'RelocObject' and I'll have a single block of memory for the heap.  This looks something like this:

```
// This class acts as an indirection to the actual object in memory so that it can be      
// relocated in the sweep phase of garbage collector
class MemBlock
{
public:
    void* Get( void ) { return m_ptr; }

private:
    MemBlock( void ) : m_ptr( NULL ){}

    void* m_ptr;
};

// This is of the same size as the above class and is directly cast to it, but is     
// typed so that we can easily debug the underlying object
template<typename _Type_>
class TypedBlock
{
public:
    _Type_* Get( void ) { return m_pObject; }

private:
    TypedBlock( void ) : m_pObject( NULL ){}

    // Pointer to actual object in memory
    _Type_* m_pObject;
};

// This is our wrapper class that every pointer is wrapped in 
template< typename _Type_ >
class RelocObject
{
public:

    RelocObject( void ) : m_pRef( NULL ) {}

    static RelocObject New( void )
    {
        RelocObject ref( (TypedBlock<_Type_>*)Allocator()->Alloc( this, sizeof(_Type_), __alignof(_Type_) ) );
        new ( ref.m_pRef->Get() ) _Type_();
        return ref;
    }

    ~RelocObject(){}

    _Type_*     operator->  ( void ) const 
    { 
        assert( m_pRef && "ERROR! Object is null\n" ); 
        return (_Type_*)m_pRef->Get(); 
    }

    // Equality
    bool operator ==(const RelocObject& rhs) const { return m_pRef->Get() == rhs.m_pRef->Get(); }
    bool operator !=(const RelocObject& rhs) const { return m_pRef->Get() != rhs.m_pRef->Get(); }

    RelocObject&    operator=   ( const RelocObject& rhs ) 
    {
        if(this == &rhs) return *this;
        m_pRef = rhs.m_pRef;
        return *this; 
    }

private:

    RelocObject( TypedBlock<_Type_>* pRef ) : m_pRef( pRef ) 
    {
        assert( m_pRef && "ERROR! Can't construct a null object\n");
    }

    RelocObject*    operator&   ( void ) { return this; }
    _Type_&     operator*   ( void ) const { return *(_Type_*)m_pRef->Get(); }

    // SS: 
    TypedBlock<_Type_>* m_pRef;
};

// We would use it like so...
typedef RelocObject<Impl::Foo> Foo;

void main( void )
{
    Foo foo = Foo::New();
}
```

So in order to find the 'root' RelocObjects when I allocate in 'RelocObject::New' I pass in the 'this' pointer of the RelocObject into the allocator(garbage collector).  The allocator then checks to see if the 'this' pointer is in the range of the memory block for the heap and if it is then I can assume its not a root.

So the issue comes when I want to trace from the roots through the child objects using the zero or more RelocObjects located inside each child object.

I want to find the RelocObjects in a class (ie a child object) using a 'precise' method.  I could use a reflection approach and make the user Register where in each class his or her RelocObjects are.  However this would be very error prone and so I'd like to do this automatically.

So instead I'm looking to use Clang to find the offsets of the RelocObjects within the classes at compile time and then load this information at program start and use this in the mark phase of the garbage collector to trace through and mark the child objects.

So my question is can Clang help? I've heard you can gather all kinds of type information during compilation using its compile time hooks.  If so what should I look for in Clang ie are there any examples of doing this kind of thing?

Just to be explicit: I want to use Clang to automatically find the offset of 'Foo' (which is a typedef of RelocObject) in FooB without the user providing any 'hints' ie they just write:

```
class FooB
{
public:
    int m_a;
    Foo m_ptr;
};
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: So how do you plan to handle a union that contains a pointer in one variant, and is overlayed by an int in another?  It seems the ability to identify a pointer "precisely" is prevented by the language design.

Comment: ... if you were to implement such a garbage collector, I'd expect you to want to use Clang to generate all the code related to GC (e.g., allocation and deallocation [e.g., you can't get rid of destructors in C++]), and it already generates code for the rest of the language.  Inside Clang you should have access to this field offset data (I'm not a Clang expert so I have not details).  But you sound like you want to do all this outside of Clang.  Why?

Comment: @Ira: I'm not so bothered about 'nice to have' features such as unions tbh. I'm able to constrain the usage pattern of my users.  Essentially I've got modules of pure C++ (where they can do anything they want) and modules that are constrained ie they aren't allowed to use raw pointers: sure they can go and use them but it'll probably break things if they do.  Think managed and unmanaged C++: both have advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: @Ira: I'm making my Impl:: classes have private ctors and dtors but friends with the garbage collector.  I don't really want Clang generating code just information about my classes.  Actually I don't want to do this outside of Clang sorry if I gave that impression: I just want Clang to dump this information out during compilation.  Maybe I neeed to reword my question a little!

Answer (score 1):

Whenever a `RelocObject` is instantiated, it's address can be recorded in a `RelocObject` ownership database along with `sizeof(*derivedRelocObject)` which will immediately identify which `Foo` belongs to which `FooB`. You don't need Clang for that. Also since `Foo` will be created shortly after `FooB`, your ownership database system can be very simple as the order of *"I've been created, here's my address and size"* calls will show the owning `RelocObject` record directly before the `RelocObject` instance's that it owns.

Each `RelocObject` has a `ownership_been_declared` flag initialized as false, upon first use (which would be after the constructors have completed, since no real work should be done in the constructor), so when any of those newly created objects is first used it requests that the database update it's ownership, the database goes through it's queue of recorded addresses and can identify which objects belong to which, clear some from it's list, setting their `ownership_been_declared` flag to true and you will have the offsets too (if you still need them).

---

p.s. if you like I can share my code for an Incremental Garbage Collector I wrote many years ago, which you might find helpful.

Comment: Firstly thanks for your detailed reply.  I want to go down the offset route because I don't want the overhead of storing pointers for every instance of a class.  I just want to generate a single offset function ie GetChildren<Foo>(this) for each class.  I'm interested though in how you've kept the ownership database simple as surely you need at least a linked list and a free list embedded in it because of random creation/deletion orders (I don't disagree that's simple btw just am interested in any tricks you might have in organising that datbase).

Comment: @user176168 apologies on the delayed response. I created a partitioned set structure (basically a structure allowing you to assign and reassign an object to a partition). I had 5 partitions, white, black, new, delete and grey (IIRC). The `Reference` structure stored two references. One would be a reference frozen at the start of each mark cycle and the other would be actively updated.